# Runtime theme selection with attributes

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I have a requirement where I have to switch application coloring/theme at runtime, for instance RedTheme and BlueTheme. I want to base both on a common theme say AppTheme 
 [image]

I can read preference and apply RedTheme or BlueTheme to activities in a base activity class and this works.

I have some variations within RedTheme or BlueTheme, for example Dialog. 
I want an activity to use Red/Blue theme but render as dialog. I am trying to use `attr` to achieve this.

```
<resources>
    <attr name="dialogActivityStyle" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

and

```
<style name="RedTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="dialogActivityStyle">@style/RedTheme.Dialog</item>
```

...

and

```
<activity android:name=".DialogActivity"
            android:theme="?attr/dialogActivityStyle"/>
```

But this does not work. It does not apply the dialog theme

Is it possible to apply theme using `attr` like I am trying to do?